# Unable to customize new layout resource file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Trying to create a xml for Tablet, but where is the qualifiers lists and everything else?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your res folder choose **New > Android Resource Directory**

Then you will see the screen like image below:

In **Resource type** choose **layout** then in **Available qualifiers** choose **size** ... see images below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now you have the folder, create activities or fragments...inside it and it will only available with screen size you choose.

Please read this:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you so much!